# Sin autorización para subir al github package registry

Tags: github, maven

Estoy tratando de publicar mi proyecto en github, en su registro de paquetes basado en [este tutorial](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-package-registry) provisto por ellos.

trato de desplegar mediante [coolbeans](/questions/tagged/coolbeans) que me genera este comando:

```
cd C:\Users\Ivana Martinez C\IdeaProjects\jcalendar; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\CoolBeans\\jre" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\CoolBeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dregistry=https://maven.pkg.github.com/javatlacati -Dtoken=1234 -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\CoolBeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 deploy\""
```

El mensaje de error que me manda es:

> ```
> Reactor Summary:
>
> JCalendar swing .................................... FAILURE [  4.820 s]
> JCalendar .......................................... SKIPPED
> JCalendar demo ..................................... SKIPPED
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> BUILD FAILURE
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Total time: 5.213 s
> Finished at: 2019-09-28T19:32:19-05:00
> Final Memory: 9M/34M
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project jcalendar-swing: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.github.javatlacati:jcalendar-swing:pom:1.3.4 from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/javatlacati/jcalendar): Failed to transfer file: https://maven.pkg.github.com/javatlacati/jcalendar/com/github/javatlacati/jcalendar-swing/1.3.4/jcalendar-swing-1.3.4.pom. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]

Mi archivo `settings.xml` es el siguiente:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>github</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>github</id>
                    <name>GitHub javatlacati Apache Maven Packages</name>
                    <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/javatlacati</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>github</id>
            <username>javatlacati</username>
            <password>1234</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

- Nota: obviamente mi tóken no es `1234`, pero ese pongo como ejemplo

Los permisos que le dí al tóken de github son:

- repo:status
- repo_deployment
- public_repo
- repo:invite
- write:repo_hook
- read:repo_hook